# How to get the geometric shape of an amount with complex numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers

I am trying to solve the following equation.

M is an amount

$$M=\left\{z\in\mathbb{C}\colon \left|\left(\sqrt 2 - i\sqrt 2\right)z+\sqrt 2i\right|=2\right\}$$

I understand that I will get a circle with a small radius, probably $1$.

But I don't know how to solve these kinds of equations. Any help is upvoted

I thought about to get rid of the roots by using $^2$, but that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$|(\sqrt 2 - i \sqrt 2)z+\sqrt 2 i|=2 \implies  |(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} - i \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} )z+\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}  i|=1 $$
$$\implies  |e^{(-i\frac{\pi}{4})}z+\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} e^{(i\frac{\pi}{2})} |=1 $$

$$\implies  |z+\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} e^{(i\frac{3\pi}{4})} |=1 $$

$$\implies  |z+\frac{-1+i}{2}  |=1 $$

So $M$ describes a circle of radius $1$ centred at $\frac{-1+i}{2}$

Comment: ...centered at $\dfrac{1-i}2$.